# jQuery.filer PHP File Uploader

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, jquery.fileapi

I am trying to use the PHP File Uploader for jQuery. https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader

I have a custom method to upload to my server, I just cant figure out what parameter to pass to my custom method from this plugin.

Comment: which jquery file upload plugin are you using ?

Comment: [filename] jQuer filer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't what you mean with custom method but in [php-uploader](https://github.com/CreativeDream/php-uploader) you can:

1. uploading method in **class.uploader.php** is `uploadFile` (currently on line 258)
2. you can also use your own callbacks ("onCheck", "onSuccess", "onUpload", "onComplete").
   Ex:

   'onUpload' => 'your_function_name_that_you_declared_anywhere_in_code'